# Rails - How to check what the record count of a model 24 hours ago

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to display the rate of change in the total number of records for a certain model.  So I need to know, at any given time, how many there were 24 hours ago, and how many there are now.
It is very likely that a record will be deleted by users, so I can't just use the value of existing records that are older than 24 hours.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :since, lambda {|time| where("created_at > ?", time) }
  scope :during_last, lambda {|time| where("created_at > ?", (Time.now - time)) }
end

Item.since(Time.now - 24.hours).count
Item.since(24.hours.ago).count
Item.during_last(24.hours).count
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do a count against the column `created_at`.

```
def count_rate(model, time=DateTime.now)
  current_count = model.count(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", time])
  last_24_hours_count = model.count(:conditions => ["created_at < ?", time-24.hours])

  current_count - last_24_hours_count
end
```

This method count the record at a given compared with the last 24 hours.

Well, in case the user has deleted those records back, you would should create another table `Rate(date, hour, count)` and record every hour by using `observer` (only `after_create`).

```
def after_create
  rate = Rate.find_or_initialize_by(Date.today.to_s, Time.now.hour)
  rate.increment(:count)
  rate.save!
end
```

In this observer, if it finds the existing record by date and hour, it simply increment the count column. You add the default value to zero on `count` column as well. Later on, you can query the data from that table by date and hour.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it is very likely that the record will be deleted by users, so the last_24_hours_count value will not necessarily be accruate.  Will update OP to reflect this.